# Exception: Correlation failed. Unknown location (Azure AD B2C)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, openid-connect, azure-ad-b2c

I have an ASP.NET Core 2.2 application with the following configuration:

[image]

And this is my Startup.cs class

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
    
    services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
    })
    .AddCookie("Cookies")
    .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
    {
        options.SignInScheme = "Cookies";
        options.Authority = $"{ Configuration.GetValue<string>("AzureAdB2C:Instance") }/{ Configuration.GetValue<string>("AzureAdB2C:Tenant")  }/{ Configuration.GetValue<string>("AzureAdB2C:SignUpSignInPolicyId") }/v2.0";
        options.ClientId = Configuration.GetValue<string>("AzureAdB2C:ClientId");
        options.ResponseType = "code id_token";
        options.SaveTokens = true;
        options.ClientSecret = Configuration.GetValue<string>("AzureAdB2C:ClientSecret");
    });

    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

}
```

When I run this the B2C login page pops-up, however once I enter the credentials I get the error below. URL is redirected to https://localhost:xxxx/signin-oidc

[image]

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Hi @JoshMonreal Web trace to see if the b2c token came back would be useful

Comment: Hi @JoshMonreal are you still looking for any help on this.?

Comment: No, I have fixed it already. Thank you.

Comment: @JoshMonreal Perhaps you would like to share how you fixed it? You know, in case somebody else with the same issue stumbles across it...

Answer (score 0):

This is the similar [issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/1824), the same error occurred when external login is canceled and redirects to the source application. You could use `OnRemoteFailure` to handle the exception.

```
AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options => {
    // ...
    options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
    {
        OnRemoteFailure = ctx =>
        {
            ctx.Response.Redirect("/error?FailureMessage=" + UrlEncoder.Default.Encode(ctx.Failure.Message)); 
            ctx.HandleResponse(); 
            return Task.FromResult(0); 
        }
    };  
});
```

Comment: Hi Pamela, I tried this but it didn't work. All I got was a FailureMessage=Correlation Failed error. 

Also, I am not using an external login; I'm using the basic one which is email and password authentication.